# How to Proceed with 3-legged OAuth 2.0 Scope Verification for Google Cloud Consent Screen? Is this possible given the situation?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, scopes

Please bear with me as there are a lot of details to include here to give you enough background to help me figure out how to proceed with getting my App Consent Screen verified on the Google Cloud Console.

**Overview**

I've submitted my app for OAuth Consent Screen verification and have had push back due to the 3-legged OAuth Scopes that I've requested. I don't believe that the "steps" Google's team provided me apply to my app and how it will be used. Maybe I'm wrong, but a second opinion would be super helpful.

**Full Background**

I run a free and open source app that allows users to self-host a "server" that essentially proxies iMessage to different clients (Windows, Android, etc.). As part of the Android integration, the server needs to be able to send notifications to the corresponding clients. It does so using Google's Firebase Messaging service. Currently, the user needs to *manually* create a Firebase project, configure an Android app for it, download the Google Services & Service Account JSON files, and apply it within the server. This setup is tedious and confusing to some less tech savvy users.

Recently, we've made an effort to implement Google Sign In to allow *my* Google Cloud Project to act as a puppeteer and do all that setup & configuration automatically (with their permission). As such, my Google Cloud Project requires the following permissions to create a Firebase project, enable the Firestore, create an Android configuration, and generate a Service Account:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management

According to Google, some of these scopes are referred to as "three-legged" OAuth 2.0 scopes because it allows users to grant access to all their data hosted within a particular API.

Fair enough.

**The Issue**

Upon submitting verification for the App, Google's team responded saying that the scopes requested have too broad access and I need to perform the following steps to remediate the concern:

1. Create a service account to access data from your users’ Google Cloud Platform project. You may want to create a service account for each customer to avoid confused deputy problems.
2. Instruct your customers to grant this service account appropriate access to their Cloud data via IAM Policies.

*The issue I see is, because the app/service is completely self-hosted and we do not have direct contact with our users, there is no way I can create a service account for each of them. Moreover, even if we just created one, my understand is each user would need to grant the service account appropriate access via their Cloud IAM policies. This would require user-intervention and would essentially nullify the effort to "make setup more seamless by automating it".*

**What Next?**

Am I completely misunderstanding what Google's team is suggesting? Is it possible for me to limit exactly what my app can have access to via IAM policies *without* having users intervene within their own Google Console?

Or, is it simply not possible to get this sort of setup to be verified, and the app will need to stay unverified?

If there is a way for me to specifically limit the app even further outside of the scopes, I am all for it. I just do not completely think that the suggestions made by the Google Team would apply to my situation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A vendor's policies are off-topic on Stack Overflow. And it does not matter what we think of Google's policies. From a security viewpoint, what you are doing has risk for customer's data. Google does want you to have access to that data. You have one of several choices 1) reduce the scopes you are requesting to meet Google's requirements. 2) Follow Google's recommendation to use a service account. If that means creating documentation for the customer, so be it. 3) Redesign how your app interacts with Google and the customer.

Comment: @JohnHanley My question wasn't criticizing Google's policies. It was more to gain clarity into if what they were requesting was possible for me to comply with. It sounds like the answer is no without having the user intervene in some way. Thank you.

Comment: I did not say you were criticizing Google's policies however, you are with this comment: `This would require user-intervention and would essentially nullify the effort to "make setup more seamless by automating it`. You asked for options about Google's policies and that is off-topic because we can only offer opinions. This [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) will help you write on-topic questions.